# Append text file with a new value without duplicate

Tags: powershell

I tried to -append existing file to add only new value found but the value always duplicated

```
$arrList=New-object System.Collections.ArrayList       
$line="201506291500-1600-1.gz","201506291500-1600-2.gz","201506291500-1600-    3.gz","201506291500-1600-9.gz"
$file="c:\users\admin\desktop\ftp\list.txt"      

$a=get-content $file

$arrList.add($a)

$line|%{if(!$arrList.contains($_)){$arrList.Add($_)}}


$arrList|out-file $file -append
```

list.txt contains 
201506291500-1600-9.gz
201506291500-1600-10.gz
201506291500-1600-11.gz

but what I'm getting of the output of list.txt is duplicate values

201506291500-1600-9.gz

201506291500-1600-10.gz

201506291500-1600-11.gz

201506291500-1600-9.gz

201506291500-1600-10.gz

201506291500-1600-11.gz

201506291500-1600-1.gz

201506291500-1600-2.gz

201506291500-1600-3.gz

201506291500-1600-9.gz

what I expected is:

201506291500-1600-1.gz

201506291500-1600-2.gz

201506291500-1600-3.gz

201506291500-1600-9.gz

201506291500-1600-10.gz

201506291500-1600-11.gz

Your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help:

```
$line="201506291500-1600-1.gz","201506291500-1600-2.gz","201506291500-1600-7.gz","201506291500-1600-9.gz"
$list = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\list.txt 
$line  | Where-Object {$_ -notin $list} | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\list.txt -Append -Encoding ascii
```